# What does a function name stand for in C

Tags: c

What does the compiler do when we define a function? And is the function name a pointer? Or maybe it's something else.

I wish I knew something about function names.

Comment: It is just the name (symbol) for compiler and linker. In will not be present in your executable\

Comment: It's just an identifier. Whenever used in most expressions it "decays" into a function pointer, just as an array name when used in most expressions "decays" to the pointer to the first element.

Comment: I think this is a good question. We should always ask ourselves what the things we are using represent and have an interest how they work underneath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does a function name stand for in C

The function name stands for the function.

> What does the compiler do when we define a function?

The compiler remembers the name of the function, and it generates code to implement the function. It also remembers information from the declaration of the function, such as the return type and the types of the parameters, if a prototype form was used.

> And is the function name a pointer? Or maybe it's something else.

The name of a function designates a function.

When a function name is used in an expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the function, with a couple of exceptions discussed below. Furthermore, effectively the only use for a function name is as a pointer to the function. Because of this, a programmer might think of the function name as a pointer, but it is not actually a pointer.

One exception to the automatic conversion is when a function name is used with `sizeof`. However, using `sizeof` on a function is usually an error (it is not defined by the C standard and can work only if a C implementation defines it as an extension), so this exception is never used in ordinary practice. The other exception is when a function name is used with unary `&`, as in `&sin`. In this case, we are explicitly taking the address of the function, which produces a pointer to the function, so there is no need for automatic conversion to a pointer to the function.

When you call a function, as with `sin(x)`, the “function-call operator,” `( … )`, takes a pointer to the function as its first operand. So, due to the automatic conversion, `sin(x)` is effectively `(&sin)(x)`, which says to call the function whose address is `&sin` and pass it the argument `x`.

The fact that the function-call operator takes a pointer to a function is why we can use pointers for functions, as in `double (*p)(double) = sin; printf("sin(.5) = %g.\n", p(.5));`.

Comment: How does a Function call operator get a pointer to a function?Can you tell me something about it

Comment: It is worth to mention that function parameter of function type are transformed to function pointers. That `int(int())` is equivalent to `int(int(*)())`